# Adapt a lending iterator type to a serde-style map visitor

Tags: rust, visitor-pattern, serde

I'm trying to adapt the data model I designed to a serde `MapAccess` interface. I have my own data model, which has a `List` type containing key-value pairs, which are exposed like this:

```rust
impl List {
    fn next_item(&mut self) -> Option<(String, Item<'_>)>
}
```

In other words, the `Item` type mutably borrows from a `List` object, and must be fully processed before the next `Item` can be extracted from the `List`.

I need to adapt this data model to a deserializer trait that looks like this:

```rust
trait MapAccess {
    fn next_key<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
    fn next_value<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> T;
}
```

The two methods should be called in alternating order; they're allowed to panic or return garbage results if you don't call them in the correct order. This trait is provided by the deserializer library I'm using, and is the one only of this problem I can't control or modify.

I'm trying to adapt a `List` or an `&mut List` into a `MapAccess` and I'm running into challenges. I do have a function which converts an `Item<'_>` to a `T: Deserialize` (and specifically ends the borrow of `List`):

```rust
fn deserialize_item<T: Deserialize>(item: Item<'_>) -> T;
```

The basic problem I'm running into is that `MapAccess::next_key` calls `List::next_item` and then deserializes the String as a key, and then needs to store the `Item<'_>` so that it can handled by `next_value`. I keep running into cases with types that are *almost* self referential (two fields that both mutably borrow the same thing). It's nothing *truely* self-referential so I'm not (yet) convinced that this is impossible. The closest I've come is some kind of enum that that resembles `enum State {List(&'a mut List), Item(Item<'_>)}` (because I don't need to access a `List` while I'm working on the `Item`, but I haven't found a way to restore access to the `List` for the next `next_key` after the `Item` is consumed.

As the author of the data model, I do have some leeway to change how it's designed, but *if possible* I'd like to hold on to some kind of borrowing model, which I use to enforce parse consistency (that is, the borrow prevents `List` from parsing the next item until after the `Item` has fully parsed the content of the current item.). I can of course design any additional types to implement this correctly.

---

Note: This is all serde related, but I'm using original types to simplify the interfaces. In particular I've omitted all the of the `Result` types and `'de` lifetimes as I'm confident they're not relevant to this problem.

---

EDIT: Here's my *attempt* to make something that works. This doesn't compile, but it hopefully gets across what I'd like to do here.

```rust
fn deserialize_string<T: Deserialize>(value: String) -> T { todo!() }
fn deserialize_item<T: Deserialize>(item: Item<'_>) -> T { todo!() }

struct ListMapAccess<'a> {
    list: &'a mut List,
    item: Option<Item<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> MapAccess for ListMapAccess<'a> {
    fn next_key<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let (key, item) = self.list.next_item()?;
        self.item = Some(item);
        Some(deserialize_string(key))
    }

    fn next_value<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> T {
        let item = self.item.expect("Called next_item out of order");
        deserialize_item(item)
    }
}
```

Now, I'm really not at all tied to a `ListMapAccess` struct; I'm happy with any solution that integrates my `List` / `Item` interface into `MapAccess`.

Comment: @Netwave `MapAccess` is a foreign trait from serde.

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward... `next_key()` advances whatever your internal iterator is and produces the key and value, which you store. `next_value()` just returns the last value that was stored by `next_key()`. If this solution doesn't work you're going to have to give more detail. Actual code would be good.

Comment: @cdhowie in theory, yes, I agree. I added a code example showing the simple implementation. The problem is that the `'a` lifetime on `Item` makes the trivial implementation of this pattern not compile; my question is about trying to find a workaround implementation. Normally I'd describe it as impossible because of self-referential problems, but in theory this can be expressed without anything self-referential; I just can't figure out what the actual solution is.

Comment: Try `fn next_key<T: Deserialize<'a>>(&'a mut self)`

Comment: I did; that ends up not working because it's no longer possible to call `next_value` afterwards, because the borrow is lengthened. And, in any case, it doesn't matter, because I don't control the `MapAccess` interface; it's defined by serde. `MapAccess` is the crux of the problem; it's the interface I'm trying to work around here.

Comment: Ah, right... I guess serde drops the value returned by `next_key()` before calling `next_value()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be impossible in safe rust, but I've come up with this unsafe solution.

```rust
// `List` is a type that I control that I'd like to adapt to
// `MapAccess`.
impl List {
    fn next_item(&mut self) -> Option<(String, Item<'_>)>
}

// Fake version of `serde::de::MapAccess`. I don't have control
// of this trait.
trait MapAccess {
    fn next_key<T: From<String>>(&mut self) -> Option<T>;
    fn next_value<T: From<Item>>(&mut self) -> T;
}

struct ListMapAccess<'a> {
    fake_list: PhantomData<&'a mut List>,
    list: NonNull<List>,
    item: Option<Item<'a>>,
}

/// Returned if you call `next_item` while `item` is not `None`
/// or if you called `use_item` while it *is* `None`
struct BorrowError;

impl<'a> ListMapAccess<'a> {
    fn next_item(&mut self) -> Result<Option<String>, BorrowError> {
        if self.item.is_some() { return Err(BorrowError) }

        // SAFETY: It's only safe to create this reference if the `item` is
        // empty, because the `item` borrows from the list. If `item` is
        // empty, then there are no "real" borrows of `List` in existence,
        // since we're pretending to own a mutable borrow in `ListMapAccess`.
        let list: &'a mut List = unsafe { self.list.as_mut() };
        let Some((key, item)) = list.next_item() else { return Ok(None) };

        self.item = Some(item);
        Ok(Some(key))
    }

    fn use_item<R>(
        &mut self,
        // The use of `for<'b>` here ensures that `op` can't
        // cause the `Item` to outlive `ListMapAccess`.
        op: impl for<'b> FnOnce(Item<'b>) -> R
    ) -> Result<R, BorrowError> {
        self.item.take().map(op).ok_or(BorrowError)
    }
}

impl MapAccess for ListMapAccess<'_> {
    fn next_key<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.next_item()
            .expect("called next_key out of order")
            .map(|key| key.into())
    }

    fn next_value<T: Deserialize>(&mut self) -> T {
        self.use_item(|item| item.into())
            .expect("called next_value out of order")
    }
}
```

The key insight here is that `ListMapAccess` has to own a `NonNull<List>`, instead of a mutable reference. We provide an API that guarantees at compile time that the list can never be mutably borrowed more than once, because it only allows a mutable borrow to be created if `self.item` (which inherently borrows the list) is empty, and prevents the item from escaping ownership by the `ListMapAccess`.

The code here is a simplification of the real-world use case (it avoids a bunch of extra lifetimes and `Result` return types that aren't relevant to the problem at hand), but the real-world version is available [here](https://github.com/Lucretiel/kaydle/blob/42ed2c8dd60add12da63fe9f2e8275f35e67b7cd/kaydle/src/serde/de/node_list.rs#L135-L228) for those who are interested.